# How to restrict a row from getting deleted from a table through a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is that possible?
I know how to do it with a program but is there any query to  do it without the support of primary or foreign key?

Comment: Different databases, different ways -- pick *one*.

Comment: You mean doing something other than adding a `WHERE some_column != 'some_value'` to the end of the query..?

Comment: @inhan no.. I want to just restrict it, whenever I try to delete that row it should say me that you cant delete it whatever query I run.

Comment: Maybe a trigger `BEFORE DELETE`? Haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL I don't think it is possible.  If the MySQL user running query has the DELETE privilege, then they will be able to delete any row.